# reactjs pagination showing undesired element when selecting backwards

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I have created a pagination form in my reactjs app but I am having some problems.
The form should work in that way that if I have around 20 elements the array which displays the elements should be like "1, 2, 3, ... ,18 ,19, 20", and if the current selected element is 10, the array should be like" 1,2,3, ..., 9,10,11,...,18,19,20".

The problem is that when I go and select the elements forward from 1 to n, it works all good, but when I go backwards from 20 to 1 it just keeps creating the "..." element multiple times. Even stranger is that when I console.log the array, the elements look as they should, but the

...

html element is still there!

Below are the pictures of the results I have now.

The result I get when I select the elements from n to 1 (the wrong result)
[image: The result I get when I select from 1 to 16]

The result I get when I select elements from 1 to n (the desired result)

[image]

What I want to do is when I select backwards the 4th element, I want to have the elements "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 14, 15, 16" but I still get the "..." element appeared unnecessarily.

My code:

```
   var pagearray=[]
   if(nPages>10)
   {
    pagearray.push(1);
    pagearray.push(2);
   
   if(currentPage == 3)
   {
    pagearray.push(3);
    pagearray.push(4);
    pagearray.push("...");
   }
   if(currentPage==4)
   {
    pagearray.push(4);
    pagearray.push(5);
    pagearray.push("...");
   }
   if(currentPage == 5)
   {
    pagearray.push(4);
    pagearray.push(5);
    pagearray.push(6);
    pagearray.push("...");
    console.log("1");
   }
   if(currentPage > 5 && currentPage<parseInt(pageNumbers[pageNumbers.length-5]))
   {
    pagearray.push("...");
    pagearray.push(currentPage-1);
    pagearray.push(currentPage);
    pagearray.push(currentPage+1);
    pagearray.push("...");
   }
   setPageArray(pagearray);
```

And then in the end I use .map function to iterate and display all elements in the desired way:

```
            {pageArray1.map(pgNumber => (
                <li key={pgNumber} 
                    className= {`page-item ${currentPage == pgNumber && pgNumber != "..." ? 'active' : ''} `} >

                    <a onClick={() => setCurrentPage(pgNumber)}  
                        className='page-link' 
                        >
                        
                        {pgNumber}
                    </a>
                </li>
              }
```

Can you please help me and tell me what am I missing here?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because of the `key={pgNumber}`, because several elements will share the same key ('...'). I would go with `` key={`${pgNumber}-${index}`} `` in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I kept getting the error about listing the items with the same key but I kept ignoring it because I thought it wasn't that important. Soon as I fixed that error with the key, the problem was solved. Thank you once again.